# Prove that if $z^n$ is a palindrome for some $n>0$, then $z$ is also a palindrome for any alphabet E.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, formal-languages, automata, palindrome

Prove that if $z^n$ is a palindrome for some $n>0$, then $z$ is also a palindrome for any alphabet E.

Here's a proof of the statement above:

Let $w = x^n$.  If $n = 1$, then the result is trivial.
Suppose $n > 1$. Then $$x^n = reverse (x^n) = (reverse  (x))^n.$$
Write this as $$x x \dots x = reverse (x) reverse (x) \dots reverse (x).$$ But $x$ and $reverse (x)$ have the same length, so that $x = reverse (x)$.

Can anyone justify this line in the proof?
$$reverse (x^n) = (reverse  (x))^n$$

Or provide an **alternative proof**.

Comment: Does $x^n$ mean concatenating $n$ copies of the string $x$ together? If so, then it is fairly obvious. It is just an extension of $reverse(ab)=reverse(b)reverse(a)$.

Comment: Not exactly that Its a little abstract than that Lets say we have an alphabet $E = {a,b}$ then $x^2 = aba aba $ and $x = aba$ and it could be different if we change alphabet or choose another palindrome word sequence

Comment: I don't see how that is different to what I wrote. In my comment I used $a$ and $b$ to stand for any two strings of symbols from the alphabet.

Comment: I apologize for my comment i realize it now. I would appreciate if you could provide the extension in the answer and also use it in this specific case. I know its obvious but i would like to see the proof style I forget the obvious

Comment: Curiously, this isn't true for integers, as $2201^3=10662526601$.

Comment: Integers are not formal languages though. They are a number system.

Comment: I know that, Adnan. I was pointing out a curiosity, not presenting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple argument proves the statement. Essentially, it proves explicitly that $\text{rev}(z^n) = (\text{rev}(z))^n$ (if you assume it, there is nothing to prove).

Before showing the argument, some preliminaries. Any word can be written as $z = z_1 \dots z_k$, where $k \geq 0$ is the length of $z$ and the $z_i$'s are single characters of any alphabet $E$.
A word $z = z_1 \dots z_k$ is *palindrome* if $z = \text{rev}(z)$ where $\text{rev}(z) = z_k \dots z_1$.

Now, let us see the proof. The hypothesis in the statement says that, for some $n > 0$, we have $z^n = \text{rev}(z^n)$. Written more explicitly, for $z = z_1 \dots z_k$, we have

\begin{align}
z^n &= \overbrace{\overbrace{z_1 \dots z_k}^z \ \cdots \ \overbrace{z_1 \dots z_k}^z}^{n \text{ times}}
\\
&=
\\
\text{rev}(z^n) &= z_k \dots z_1 \ \cdots \ z_k \dots z_1
\end{align}

(Note that the first occurrence of $z_k$ in $\text{rev}(z^n)$ corresponds to the last occurrence of $z_k$ in $z^n$; and the first occurrence of $z_{k-1}$ in $\text{rev}(z^n)$ corresponds to the last occurrence of $z_{k-1}$ in $z^n$; and so on. This is the way to construct $\text{rev}(z^n)$ from $z^n$.)

Since $n > 0$, the identity $z^n = \text{rev}(z^n)$ holds in particular for the first $k$ characters of $z^n$ and $\text{rev}(z^n)$, hence
\begin{align}
z = z_1 \dots z_k = z_k \dots z_1 = \text{rev}(z)
\end{align}
Therefore, $z$ is palindrome.

---

Note that we have not assumed that $\text{rev}(z^n) = (\text{rev}(z))^n$. Actually, the fact that $\text{rev}(z^n) = (\text{rev}(z))^n$ is an immediate consequence of what we have proved.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array}{rcl} z^k \in \text{Palindrome} &\implies& z^k = \text{rev}(z^k) \\
&\implies& z^k{}_1 = z^k{}_{kn}~,~z^k{}_2 = z^k{}_{kn-1}~,~z^k{}_3 = z^k{}_{kn-2}~,~\dots \\
&\implies& z_1 = z_n~,~z_2 = z_{n-1}~,~z_3 = z_{n-2}~,~\dots \\
&\implies& z \in \text{Palindrome}
\end{array}$$

Third line follows from $z^k{}_{a} = z_{a ~\rm{mod}~ n}$